# Saving NSMutableArray with NSUserDefaults in Swift Returns Nil

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, save, nsuserdefaults

I have a `NSMutableArray`. Here is how I save it with `NSUserDefaults`:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(downloadedFile as NSMutableArray, forKey: "myKey")
```

And here how I retrieve it:

```
var downloadedFilesFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray = defaults.objectForKey("myKey") as NSMutableArray
```

Comment: It returns nil, whatever i do. Is there a bug or something?

Comment: did You Do defaults.synchronize()  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take look at this and try to save you array like this! as this worked perfectly!

```
var arr:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray(objects: "ASD","aSd")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(arr, forKey: "Array")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

on button click

```
NSLog("%@", NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("Array") as NSMutableArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like swift somehow release my object i needed to make sure that my object is not nil.