# Swift 3 UserDefaults set NSMutableArray

Tags: swift, swift3, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, userdefaults

[Saving NSMutableArray with NSUserDefaults in Swift Returns Nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798236/saving-nsmutablearray-with-nsuserdefaults-in-swift-returns-nil)

`setObject` method removed my codes like that and not work. i try all set types still not work. Any idead ?

```
var banksAccount : NSMutableArray = []

for bankJson in (self.users?[0].Banks)! {
    self.banksAccount.add(bankJson)
}

UserDefaults.standard.set(self.banksAccount, forKey: "myBanksAccounts")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

For saving

```
let cacheArrayData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: banksAccount)
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(cacheArrayData, forKey: "EventItems")
```

For retrieving

```
let retriveArrayData = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:  "EventItems") as? NSData
                let retriveArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: retriveArrayData! as Data) as? NSArray
                self.eventsArray = NSMutableArray(array:retriveArray!)
```

Comment: 2017-11-25 14:18:45.017745+0300 MyApp[22186:298457] *** NSForwarding: warning: object 0x600000299f00 of class 'MyApp.Bank' does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[MyApp.Bank replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]
2017-11-25 14:18:45.018325+0300 MyApp[22186:298457] Unrecognized selector -[MyApp.Bank replacementObjectForKeyedArchiver:]

Comment: @GökhanÇokkeçeci banksAccount this should be NSArray